# Split data from one column and update in the other

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I want to update a column with the data from the other column.

Record:- `Hello MP123`

I want to update `MP123` in the other column using update query in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to update the records.

```
Update table_name 
set column_2 = substr(column1,start,end);
```

You can use **INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [, th_appearance ] ] )**
 to get the start and end position.

```
update temp_table_sub 
set column_2 = substr(column1,instr(column1,' ') +1  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` string function

```
update tab 
   set col1 = replace(col1,'MP123',col2)
```

> The syntax for the `replace` function in `Oracle SQL` / `PLSQL` :
>
> `replace( string1, string_to_replace [, replacement_string] )`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=df7d18e3976e0ea97fa1ecb9fe87c682)</kbd>